# Parse large XML file over FTP

Tags: php

I need to parse a large XML file (>1 GB) which is located on a FTP server. I have a FTP stream aquired by ftp_connect(). (I use this stream for other FTP-related actions)

I know XMLReader is preferred for large XML files, but it will only accept a URI. So I assume a stream wrapper will be required. And the only ftp-function I know of which will allow me to retrieve only a small part of the file is ftp_nb_fget() in combination with ftp_nb_continue().

However, I do not know how I should put all of this together to make sure that a minimum amount of memory is used.

Comment: If you have to parse the entire file, it may be better to simply download the whole thing first and work off that, rather than having to mess with streams and whatnot.

Comment: That would certainly be easier. But I feel it would be more efficient to do both downloading and parsing at the same time. I have no need to save the file to the harddrive.

Comment: I guess if the XML doesn't nest itself too deep (e.g. a single `<val>1</val>` nested a kajillion layers down), parse-as-you-go would make sense then.

Comment: The entries (elements) wont be larger than a few KB, and should not nest deeper than 4 elements. I think my biggest problem is memory management. ftp_nb_fget() wont let me specify how many bytes to read, and I'm not sure how it would react if I remove data from the file handle ($handle) when I'm finished with that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may need to [build on top of the low-level XML parser bits](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.xml.php).

In particular, you can use [`xml_parse`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse.php) to process XML one chunk of the XML string at a time, after calling the various `xml_set_*` functions with callbacks to handle elements, character data, namespaces, entities, and so on.  Those callbacks will be triggered whenever the parser detects that it has enough data to do so, which *should* mean that you can process the file as you read it in arbitrarily-sized chunks from the FTP site.

---

Proof of concept using CLI and [`xml_set_default_handler`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-set-default-handler.php), which will get called for everything that doesn't have a specific handler:

```
php > $p = xml_parser_create('utf-8');
php > xml_set_default_handler($p, function() { print_r(func_get_args()); });
php > xml_parse($p, '<a');
php > xml_parse($p, '>');
php > xml_parse($p, 'Foo<b>Bar</b>Baz');
Array
(
    [0] => Resource id #3
    [1] => <a>
)
Array
(
    [0] => Resource id #3
    [1] => Foo
)
Array
(
    [0] => Resource id #3
    [1] => <b>
)
Array
(
    [0] => Resource id #3
    [1] => Bar
)
Array
(
    [0] => Resource id #3
    [1] => </b>
)
php > xml_parse($p, '</a>');
Array
(
    [0] => Resource id #3
    [1] => Baz
)
Array
(
    [0] => Resource id #3
    [1] => </a>
)
php >
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time! This would certainly solve my parsing problems. But how would you propose that I fetch the data from the FTP server while keeping memory usage low? I'm concerned because I'm not in control of how much data is read when I call ftp_nb_fget() and ftp_nb_continue()

Comment: `ftp_nb_get` actually creates a local file.  The contents of the file won't be kept in memory.  You'll need to actually open it up and read it (while the download is happening asynchronously) separately.  It's the reading back in of that file that might consume memory, but if you use [`fread`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) to read only small sized chunks at once, you should be OK, at least as far as that is concerned.  (You might need to use `ftell`/`fseek` to allow reading again, if you hit EOF early.)  (continued)

Comment: On the other hand, you will need to take care to properly dispose of data while performing the XML parsing, otherwise you will very quickly use quite a bit of memory.  You can periodically [probe your current memory use](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) and log it, if you're concerned.

Comment: If I use ftp_nb_fget() I'll be able to use fopen('php://memory') as $handle

Comment: True, or you could even create a custom stream handler that processes the XML file directly.  That *might* be a bit overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I never tried that with FTP, but setting the Stream Context can be done with

- [`libxml_set_streams_context` — Set the streams context for the next libxml document load or write](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-set-streams-context.php)

Then just put in the FTP URI in [`open()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.open.php).

**EDIT:** Note that you can use the Stream Context for other actions as well. If you are uploading files, you can probably use the same stream context in combination with `file_put_contents`, so you dont necessarily need any of the ftp* functions at all.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that function. However I would prefer to avoid using a FTP URI (such as ftp://server/file) since I have already established a connection with ftp_connect()

Comment: @Troubled and do you actually do anything with that connection?

Comment: @Troubled well, how much overhead can closing and reopening be? I'd give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on the schema of your XML file.  But if it's something similar to RSS in that it's really just a long list of items (all encapsulated in a tag), then what I've done is to parse out the individual sections, and parse them as individual domdocuments:

```
$buffer = '';
while ($line = getLineFromFtp()) {
    $buffer .= $line;
    if (strpos($line, '</item>') !== false) {
        parseBuffer($buffer);
        $buffer = '';
    }
}
```

That's pseudo code, but it's a light way of handling a specific type of XML file without building your own XMLReader.  You'd of course need to check for opening tags as well, to ensure that the buffer is always a valid xml file.

Note that this won't work with all XML types.  But if it fits, it's a easy and clean way of doing it while keeping your memory footprint as low as possible...